# Attempting to find the shortest path

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have the following code, which I thought would recurse through nodes and once it reaches the goal, return the shortest. But I'm getting Stack Overflow.

**Note:** *GetConnectedParts is a method of Part, with the current setup it returns each accessible node.*

**Note2:** *There IS a path from start to finish, multiple actually.*

My code is here, and I'd be thankful for any help you can provide:

```
function FindPath(start, finish, path)
    --Define a table to hold the paths
    local paths = {}
    --Make a default argument
    path = path or {start}
    --Loop through connected nodes
    for i,v in ipairs(start:GetConnectedParts()) do --Overflow occurs here
        --Determine if backtracking
        local loop = false
        for i,vv in ipairs(path) do
            if v == vv then
                loop = true
            end
        end
        if not loop then
            --Make a path clone
            local npath = {unpack(path)}
            if v == finish then
                --If we reach the end add the path
                paths[#paths+1] = npath
            else
                --Otherwise add the shortest part extending from this node
                paths[#paths+1] = FindPath(v, finish, npath)
            end
        end
    end
    --Find and return the shortest path
    local lengths = {}
    for i,v in ipairs(paths) do
        lengths[#lengths+1] = #v
    end
    local least = math.min(unpack(lengths))
    for i,v in ipairs(paths) do
        if #v == least then
            return v
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow. My problem was actually easily solved. I wasn't putting parts inside the path itself. Sorry for the confusion.